# Getting error in installing executables (.msi/.exe) on remote servers using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, remote-access, remote-desktop, remote-server, powershell-4.0

I have a list of executables(`.msi` and `.exe`) which I have to install on some remote servers (in same domain) *silently* using `PowerShell` script. For that first I am copying all programs from local server to remote servers. Next I am trying to install all these programs one by one to the remote servers. For that I am using below code:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\path\to\softwares\*" -Destination "C:\path\to\destination"  # this is copying all softwares on destination path

$destItem = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\path\to\destination"

foreach($software in $destItem)
{
    $setup = Invoke-Command -ComputerName <computer> -ScriptBlock {$temp=Start-Process "C:\path\to\$software" -ArgumentList "/s" -Wait -PassThrough;$Temp}
}
```

**Problem is:** When I run this script I get the following error:

> [172.xx.xx.xxx] Connecting to remote server 172.xx.xx.xxx failed with the following error message : The WinRM client
>   cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the
>   transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use
>   winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For more
>   information on how to set TrustedHosts run the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (172.xx.xx.xxx:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotUseIPAddress,PSSessionStateBroken

I ran command `winrm quickconfig` on local machine and got this result:

```
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

and from remote servers got this output:

```
WinRm already is set up to recieve requests on this machine.
WinRm already is set up for remote management on this machine.
```

- Windows version: Windows Server 2012R2
- PS version: 4

**Question is:** How can I resolve this issue and can install executables on remote servers?

Comment: Someone down voted this question without telling why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try to put the remote computer into the list of trusted hosts:

- View the list of TrustedHosts
  `get-item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts`
- Add all computers (be careful!) to the list of TrustedHosts
  `set-item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -value *`
- Add a computer with a specific IP address to the list of Trusted Hosts
  `set-item wsman:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -value 192.168.0.10`

Comment: I have already run all these commands from command prompt before posting here, should I need to use these commands in my script? if yes, then how? can you explain?

Comment: No.. they don't need to be in script, you have to add them once. The error message states that you have to pass credentials: The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, **and explicit credentials** are provided

Comment: Which credentials and how to provide that? What would be the command to do so?

Comment: You pass the credentials (Username and password for the remote computer) as parameter to `$c=get-credential; invoke-command -credential $c ...`

Comment: There are many remote computers and I have to install executables _silently_ in each computer.

Answer (score 1):

Check Matt Wrock's article about remotely installing software on windows:

http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/safely-running-windows-automation-operations-that-typically-fail-over-winrm-or-powershell-remoting

In his Boxstarter library he tackles this by wrapping the commands in a scheduled task using the Invoke-FromTask command:

```
Invoke-FromTask @"
    Start-Process "$env:temp\net45.exe" -verb runas -wait `
      -argumentList "/quiet /norestart /log $env:temp\net45.log"
"@
```